# Dual-boot with multiple users

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, hard-drive

I am building a PC that will be used by two people. One user (me) needs to use both windows and ubuntu. The second user will only be using windows. Before I buy the hardware I would like to make sure that what I want to do is achievable and makes sense.

My plan is to have

- 1 SSD for windows installation and programs, which I'd like to be available by both users
- 1 SSD for ubuntu installation and programs, which only I will be using
- 1 HDD for each user's documents and media. I want to have some privacy between us here, and I want to be able to access my documents from both windows and ubuntu.

I am not totally sure how I should setup the HDD and the user-accounts/permissions in order to achieve this, if it is possible at all. From what I learned I can:

1. Create a NTFS partition that can be accessed by both windows and ubuntu.
2. Create two partitions in my hard-drive and add/deny windows user-accounts to specific partitions, such that our documents are private.

I am wondering if 1) and 2) are compatible. Can I still access an NTFS that was assigned to a windows-user-account from ubuntu? If yes, would I be able to access the partitions of both windows-users-accounts from ubuntu? (which I don't want)

I should specify that the two users trust each-other and wouldn't intentionally want to get into each-other's files. So I don't need a super-safe solution regarding privacy.
Also, I will be primarily working on ubuntu and don't want to have to cut down on performance by using a virtual-machine to run ubuntu.

Sorry if my question is not very concrete, my knowledge is restricted and I don't have access to the setup I want to try things on yet.

Thanks a lots for advice and suggestions!

Comment: Ubuntu and Windows can readily co-exist on the same SSD/HDD: You do not *need* extra storage hardware. You do not need extra partitions for sharing between Windows and Ubuntu. You do not need extra partitions for sharing among users in Ubuntu. You might change your mind about some of your decisions after a few months using Ubuntu and Windows together, so be open to the idea that a afternoon of backup-and-reinstall is not a bad thing. When running dual-boot, good backups are critical. Consider experimenting in a VM until your system is built...and perhaps afterward, too.

Comment: You don’t need two SSDs. One larger one will probably be cheaper per GB than two smaller drives. Most SSDs are potentially faster in the larger capacities. I could be wrong but with NTFS a Ubuntu user can access everything regardless of NTFS permissions